# Reorder divs with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to figure out a way to handle responsiveness by reordering divs. I am trying to look for the most flexible solution but any is fine.

**View for desktop:**
[image]

**View for Mobile:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has a nice system for this out of the box.  You can push/pull columns around at different screen sizes.  Doesn't require any javascript, just some new classes.  Check out their documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

And a good tutorial on it:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Use the `push` `pull` classes to reorder them when you you are in a larger view. Bootstrap has a whole section about this here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering